# update 1.1 to 4.0 issues on defination getisimpersonationenabled not in base

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project to upgrade to 4.0 framework of .net.

getisimpersonationenabled defination is not defined in basepage for the code. is there any alternate for it ?

```
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (base.getisimpersonationenabled == "1")
        {
            if (base.UpdateSessiondata("0", "0") == "Success")
            {
                base.Response.Redirect("echome.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Logout();
            base.Response.Redirect("sitelogin.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since `getisimpersonationenabled` returns no hits from google, it's not something built in to .NET - so how are we meant to know anything about it?

Comment: Where (in which assembly/namespace) is this function defined ?

Comment: we cant help you without code..

Comment: here is the part of the code

Comment: How is `getisimpersonationenabled` defined in the base page?